# Stack overflow in recursive function

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a simple app that outputs all files in some directory to console. To achieve  this I dynamically allocate memory in function `PathCreator()` and return a pointer to this memory. I don't know how to correctly free this memory segment in `GetAllFiles()`. When I use the code below I get a stack overflow exception. How can I fix this? Please don't offer me to use something that doesn't need dynamically allocated memory, I just want to fix my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
wchar_t *PathCreator(wchar_t *dir, wchar_t *fileName);
int is_directory(wchar_t *p)
{
    wchar_t *t = PathCreator(p,L"\\");
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file;
    HANDLE search_hendle = FindFirstFile(t, &file);
    long error = GetLastError();
    if(error == 267)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

wchar_t *PathCreator(wchar_t *dir, wchar_t *fileName)
{
    wchar_t* path = 0;
    int size = 0;
    wchar_t *d = dir;
    wchar_t *f = fileName;
    while(*d != '\0')
    {
        d++;
        size++;
    }
    while(*f != '\0')
    {
        f++;
        size++;
    }
    path = new wchar_t[(size+=3) * sizeof(wchar_t)];
    int j = 0;
    while(j < size)
    {
        path[j] = '\0';
        j++;
    }
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while(*dir != '\0')
    {
        path[i] = *dir;
        i++;
        dir++;
    }
    path[i++] = '\\';
    wchar_t *t = fileName;  
    while(*t != '\0')
    {
        path[i] = *t;
        i++;
        t++;
    }
    path[i] = '\0';
    return path;
} 

void GetAllFiles(wchar_t* dir)
{
    wchar_t *p = 0;

    int i = 0;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file;
    wchar_t *t = PathCreator(dir, L"*");
    HANDLE search_hendle = FindFirstFile(t, &file);
    if(search_hendle)
    {

        do
        {
            p = PathCreator(dir,file.cFileName);
            if(!is_directory(p))
            {
                std::wcout << p << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                GetAllFiles(p);
            }
            delete [] p;
        }
        while(FindNextFile(search_hendle, &file));

    }
    delete [] t;
    FindClose(search_hendle);
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    GetAllFiles(L"C:\\Users");
}
```

Comment: @John Dibling Can you describe this more detail?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: C and C++ are not the same language. Since it's clear that you're using C++, it might be a good idea to work on your C++ concepts. For example why `new` and `delete` are discouraged (in favor of smart pointers), and why using `std::string` (or `std::wstring`) is preferred over messing with C-style string pointers.

Comment: Instead of using a recursive method, use an iterative one.

Comment: Why use such a complex function to allocate memory ? Can you not use wstring ?

Comment: @tenfour Can I fix my code without adding any extra changing(exept free memory) or this is bull shit and I sould change it radicaly?

Comment: Why are you multiplying by sizeof(wchar_t), operator new already figures out type size for you.

Comment: @Alexandre P. Levasseur I'm knew in C++ and I want to training with low level concepts. I think this is good example. But I don't know how I can solve this concrete situation.

Comment: Your code has so many problems: mixing C and C++, handle leaks, failing to check to the `"."` and `".."` entries, and probably more.

Comment: @Vsevywniy here's my suggestion: if you want to train with low level concepts don't intermingle them freely with high level concepts. This works in the other direction as well too. Clear separation and abstraction and very valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again you try to use `C` in place of `C++` and you still using `wcout`?! no problem you are a programmer and I'm sure you have a reason for this! but memory management in `C` is much much harder than `C++` and you should have some skills to use it. Here is a fully working code but as you see it is really harder to manage, use and understand than its C++ version using standard containers and string, so if you are allowed to use C++(as you use `wcout`) then use its C++ version for ease:

```
#include <Windows.h>
/*! \brief Merge \a folder and \a filename into a newly allocate memory and
 * return it to the caller. Use free to free returned memory!
 */
wchar_t* PathCreator( wchar_t const* folder, wchar_t const* filename )
{
    wchar_t* res;
    size_t i, len, folderLen = wcslen( folder ), filenameLen = wcslen( filename );
    len = folderLen + filenameLen;
    if( folder[folderLen - 1] != '\\' ) ++len;
    ++len;  // for \0

    res = (wchar_t*) malloc( sizeof(wchar_t) * len );
    if( !res ) return NULL;

    wcscpy_s( res, len, folder );
    /* Remove possible wide card at end of folder */
    for( i = folderLen; i--; ) {
        if( res[i] == '*' || res[i] == '?' ) {
            res[i] = 0;
            --folderLen;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if( res[folderLen - 1] != '\\' ) wcscat_s( res, len, L"\\" );
    wcscat_s( res, len, filename );

    return res;
}
/*! \brief Free memory that returned by \ref GetAllFiles
 */
void FreeAllFilesMemory( wchar_t** p )
{
    wchar_t** tmp = p;
    if( !p ) return ;
    while( *tmp ) free( *tmp++ );
    free( p );
}
wchar_t** AddToArray( wchar_t** p, size_t* pAllocated, size_t* pUsed, wchar_t* s )
{
    if( *pUsed >= *pAllocated ) {
        size_t newAlloc = *pAllocated * 3 / 2;  // Grow by 1.5
        if( newAlloc < 16 ) newAlloc = 16;
        p = (wchar_t**) realloc( p, newAlloc * sizeof(wchar_t*) );
        if( !p ) return NULL;
        *pAllocated = newAlloc;
    }

    p[*pUsed] = s;
    ++*pUsed;
    return p;
}
wchar_t** GetAllFilesImpl( wchar_t const* folder, wchar_t** res, size_t* pAllocated, size_t* pUsed )
{
    HANDLE hSearch;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW fileinfo;
    size_t allocatedMemory = 0;

    hSearch = FindFirstFileW( folder, &fileinfo );
    if( hSearch != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        do {
            wchar_t* sFileName, ** tmp, sTmp[ 1024 ];
            /* ignore ., .. */
            if( !wcscmp(fileinfo.cFileName, L".") ||
                !wcscmp(fileinfo.cFileName, L"..") )
                continue;
            sFileName = PathCreator( folder, fileinfo.cFileName );
            wprintf( L"%s\n", sFileName );  /* Print result */
            tmp = AddToArray( res, pAllocated, pUsed, sFileName );
            if( !tmp ) return FreeAllFilesMemory(res), NULL;
            res = tmp;
            if( fileinfo.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY ) {
                wcscpy_s( sTmp, sFileName );
                wcscat_s( sTmp, L"\\*" );
                tmp = GetAllFilesImpl( sTmp, res, pAllocated, pUsed );
                if( !tmp ) return NULL;
                res = tmp;
            }
        } while( FindNextFileW(hSearch, &fileinfo) );
        FindClose( hSearch );
    }
    return res;
}
/*! \brief List all files that match a pattern and return it as an array of
 * wide strings, free result using \ref FreeAllFilesMemory
 */
wchar_t** GetAllFiles( wchar_t const* folder )
{
    size_t nAllocated = 0, nUsed = 0;
    wchar_t** res = GetAllFilesImpl( folder, NULL, &nAllocated, &nUsed );
    if( res ) {
        /* to indicate end of result add a NULL string */
        wchar_t** tmp = AddToArray( res, &nAllocated, &nUsed, NULL );
        if( !tmp ) return FreeAllFilesMemory(res), NULL;
        res = tmp;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: O man, it's magic. It's what I've searched. How are you write this code so quickly? Are you know that I'll ask this question?))

Comment: No I'm programming C/C++ for 12 years day and night, but it take 10 minutes for I to write it, but for its C++ version I write it in a minute or two. So this is what I say it is really, really harder to code in C, so for you sake use C++ :)

Comment: I have a problem with PathCreator function. It ignores Cirillic parameters. When ASCII 'A' parameter and cirillic 'П' parameter send to function it return only "A". If two parameters are cirillic it returns nothing. But why, all function are UNICODE safety, wchar_t UNICODE safety too???

Answer (score 8):

So, you have "." and ".." in your directory search.

The first entry is ".", so:

```
p = PathCreator(dir, file.cFilename)
```

yields:

```
"C:\Users\."
```

Then the next line:

```
if (!is_directory(p))
```

Is ALWAYS false, so it just keeps recursing into:

```
GetAllFiles(p)
```

forever ... or until your stack blows up, whichever comes first ;-)

I would recommend explicitly checking for "." and ".." and skipping those entries (also MFC and Qt, etc. have nice directory handling classes, but I think you want to do it this way).

My modification:

```
    do
    {

        // I added this - guess I can't embolden code text
        if (wcscmp(file.cFileName,L".") == 0 || wcscmp(file.cFileName,L"..")==0)
            continue;

        p = PathCreator(dir,file.cFileName);
        if(!is_directory(p))
        {
            std::wcout << p << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            GetAllFiles(p);
        }
        delete [] p;
    }
    while(FindNextFile(search_hendle, &file));
```

Comment: If I change code to skip directories "." and ".." it would be work? Other things are correct?

Comment: @Vsevywniy: Mostly, I added the test (see mod above) and it recurses my C:\Users directory properly. There's an error later on in PathCreator() where it's getting a string without a null terminator, but that's another question ;-)

Comment: When I use your loop it works without crashing but it displays nothing. I think if problem - zero terminated string, there is garbage have appearence or crash? But it display nothing.